# DotNet Maui bottom drawer

Tags: bottom-sheet, maui

I tried recreating David Orinaus example of a bottom drawer on Xamarin Forms with DotNet Maui.

Implementation of bottom drawer:

```xml
<Grid>
        <!-- Backdrop -->
        <BoxView Color="#4B000000"
                 Opacity="0"
                 InputTransparent="True"
                 x:Name="Backdrop">
            <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
        </BoxView>

        <!-- Bottom Drawer -->
        <Frame
            x:Name="BottomToolbar"
            HeightRequest="200"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
            CornerRadius="20"
            TranslationY="260"
            Padding="15,6">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer
                    PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated"
            />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,4">
                <BoxView CornerRadius="2" HeightRequest="4" WidthRequest="40"
                         BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                         HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="Actions"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <TableView Intent="Settings"
                   VerticalOptions="End"
                   BackgroundColor="White"
                   >
                    <TableSection>
                        <TextCell
                            Text="Favorite"/>
                        <TextCell
                            Text="Share"/>
                    </TableSection>
                </TableView>
            </StackLayout>

        </Frame>
    </Grid>
```

Most of the code is the same and this is a sample repository: https://github.com/MaticDiba/MauiAppBottomDrawer
But for some reason, the Bottom drawer is always shown when the page is loaded instead of being hidden until called.

Is there any specific with how DotNet Maui is handling frame views? Any suggestion on how to achieve the same effect with DotNet Maui as this example did with Xamarin?

Comment: please post the relevant code inline, properly formatted, instead of just linking to an external repo

Comment: I test the sample on the github on both android and windows. The  TranslationY="260" in the Frame seems not work in android and when I click the clear menu directly without clicking the action menu, it also doesn't work. But it works on windows. So it seems a bug for android.